# C# wmi query exception

Tags: c#, exception, textbox, wmi

I have a textbox in my app that displays some system info using wmi queries & registry reading. The issue is that some systems don't display some of the info because of corruption in the OS ( processor: not available etc), so there is no way to retrieve that info using my methods or from within the OS for that matter. 
All this results in my app crashing.
How would I go about avoiding the crash and displaying a text instead for each line that can't be retrieved. EX: NOT AVAILABLE 
My textbox code is:

```
private void TextBox1_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate (object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {

        });
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(delegate (object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0", "ProcessorNameString", null).ToString().Replace("(R)", "").Replace("(TM)", "") + Environment.NewLine;
            TextBox1.Text += "Memory: " + getRAMsize() + Environment.NewLine;
            TextBox1.Text += "Free Space: " + GetTotalFreeSpace(sysdrive) + " GB" + Environment.NewLine;
            TextBox1.Text += diskname() + Environment.NewLine;
            if (Is64BitSystem)
            {
                TextBox1.Text += getOS() + " 64bit" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox1.Text += getOS() + " 32bit" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(TextBox1.Text);
        });
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use try catach to avoid application crash:

```
 string ProcessorNameString = "ProcessorNameString: not available";
        string memory = "Memory: not availbale ";
        string freeSpace = "Free space: not available";
        //add others 
                   try
        {
            ProcessorNameString = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0", "ProcessorNameString", null).ToString().Replace("(R)", "").Replace("(TM)", "") + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        catch{}

        try
        {
            memory = string.Format("Free Space:{0}DB", getRAMsize());
        }
        catch { }

        try
        {
            //freeSpace here 
        }
        catch { }
        TextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}"
            , ProcessorNameString, Environment.NewLine
            , memory, Environment.NewLine
            , freeSpace, Environment.NewLine);
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be correct. if even one of them is missing all will be disaplayed Not available

Comment: wrapper processNameString, memory , fressSpace etc. with try catach clause respectly

Comment: I have copy/pasted the code as provided. Went in a windows 7 Virtual machine and deleted "ProcessorNameString" form the registry. result = all other strings are displayed as not available, even though they have nothing to do with that specific registry key. Sorry...

Comment: my last code is exaclty the code you provided, nothing modified. I wanted to test exactly. Anyway I think you have put on the right path. Doing try/catch for each query/line seems to work

Comment: one parameter， one try catch，refer to  latest modified answer